# adding calender in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

**i want to load a calender in my text box i m working in asp.net and mvc**

[image]

*i want to load the text in red tex box i m writing this code*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**i m doing tis in my js**

[image]

**and i m doing this in my view bag i just want to show that i m adding libraries in my view bag**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chkList.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Why are you loading jquery multiple times,`jquery.min.js` and `jquery.min.js`, Aslo you should add your JS file at the end of above list

Comment: or please give us the fiddle..

Comment: bro jquery.min.js is loading just 1 time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dt = Request.Form[txtDate.UniqueID];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the example..

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```